# Which ip do I have to use when configuring my wireless repeater?

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, repeater

I want to configure a TP Link WA730 Wireless repeater, but Im having lots of trouble when assigning the correct IP address for this repeater.

Main router LAN settings:

[image]

And those are the default settings when configuring the repeater, I´ve tried with those default parameters, in the ip field with 192.168.2.254 and 192.168.1.254 but nothing (I get internet connection sometimes, after a while the connection is gone), what am I doing wrong?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

When setting up a LAN, all devices should be on the same Subnet, but it's not the case with the configuration you are using, the router is 192.168.2.1 so the repeater should be 192.168.2.* (so 192.168.2.5 would work for instance).

Indeed, submask is 255.255.255.0 it means that you can only change the last part of the IP adress (192.168.2.Change_Here).

Comment: Karlo, can you click on the check button if my answer was helpful for your problem. Thank you